# Integrating nfc with react native Expo

Tags: react-native, nfc

I'm learning React Native. For the App I am trying to build I need NFC read. As far as I know Expo supports NFC for newer IOS versions.

There are some libraries that introduce NFC to react native. But can I use normal React Native [Libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-nfc) with Expo? will that work?

Answer (score 3):

NFC isn't supported by Expo yet. And it is not possible to add libraries with native code when using Expo.

See: https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/nfc-support

Comment: I think this answer might need an update.

Comment: any update so far?